# How to combine arrays in php so that the second array overwrites the first?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have:

```
$arr1 = array('green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red');
$arr2 = array('yellow', black, white, 'red');
```

if I do `array_merge($arr1, $arr2,)` this gives:

```
array(green, yellow, blue, red, yellow, black, white, red);
```

I want to ensure that there are no duplicates in the array, note that I am not using array keys, only values.

**Is there another simple solution I am missing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_unique( array_merge( $arr1, $arr2 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that on PHP.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$unique_array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2, .... ));
```

Also from the docs please note that if you are going to use keys
`"Note that keys are preserved. array_unique() sorts the values treated as string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all following keys"`

**PRO TIP:** Terrible naming, you should use better names than I did

Answer (score 1):

simply use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) to remove all non-unique values:

```
$merged = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
```